# Android WebView callstack exceeded error on OAuth callback URL

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, oauth

I have a `WebView` in which users can log in to my online service by using other online services.

Logging in works fine on Desktop and the Android Chrome browser, but when I use the `WebView` in my App, I get a callback stack size exceeded error.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, source: THE_CALL_BACK_URL
```

The Webview adds a `www` prefix to the url, which could probably lead to the URL not being recognized by the OAuth service. Buw how do I remove the `www` prefixing?

Or could this be cause by something else?

`Code:`

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebVieCient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onRecievedError(); // Stump for brevity

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading() // Stump for brevity
    // This function handles internal links in WebView and opens external links in standard browser. 
    // (The function responds to the callback link as an internal link and opens it in the WebView)
```

#### EDIT

I have removed the `www` Prefix and i still get the Maximum call stack error